# CSS content:url() not working on anything other than chrome. Change the <img> src using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the logo of my navbar on scroll using css. It already changes color on scroll using the `.affix` class provided by bootstrap.

```
<a  href="#"><img class="limg"  src="images/firstlogo.png" /></a>
```

Only way i found how to do this was:

```
 #custom-nav.affix .limg{
 content: url(../images/secondlogo.png);}
```

**which works perfectly on chrome**. However it doesnt work on Firefox / IE / Microsoft Edge.

There seems to be a solution using ::before and ::after prefixes but those didnt work for me.
It could be caused by the following JS code which implements the affix class on scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
} else {
    $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
}
});
```

If so, is there anyway i can change that `<img src"">` using JS when `affix` activates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your image `src` attribute in `scroll` callback:

```
    var startImg = "images/firstlogo.png",
        scrollImg = "images/secondlogo.png",
        $img = $('.limg');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
            $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");

            // Set scrolling src
            $img.attr('src', scrollImg);
        } else {
            $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");

            // Set default image src
            $img.attr('src', startImg);
        }
    });
```

### Example with timeout

As mentioned bellow, it may cause some performance problems because of many calls to DOM elements, so heres improved version with `timeout` and cached DOM vars:

```
var startImg = "images/firstlogo.png",
  scrollImg = "images/secondlogo.png",
  $navBar = $(".navbar"),
  $customNav = $('#custom-nav'),
  $navBar = $(".navbar-fixed-top"),
  $img = $('.limg'),

  timeout;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
    // Use timeout to not call function immediately
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if ($navBar.offset().top > 50) {
        $customNav.addClass('affix');
        $navBar.addClass("top-nav-collapse");

        // Set scrolling src
        $img.attr('src', scrollImg);
      } else {
        $customNav.removeClass('affix');
        $navBar.removeClass("top-nav-collapse");

        // Set default image src
        $img.attr('src', startImg);
      }
    }, 250)
  });
```

Comment: WAIT. DONE IT. just cut the first 3 lines of your code and pasted them inside $window function just before 'if' statement and it worked. Thank you so much. Cant upvote your post since i dont have enough rep tho :(

Comment: This code has performance issues. `scroll` event will fire tons of times in a single scroll movement. It will cause serious lost of performance and the image src will update tons of times in a single scroll movement. To improve this code, add a `debounce` function.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude well it may cause some problems if there were lots of elements, but in current case I don't think there will be some. But I've added improved example with debounce.

Comment: @t1m0n yeah, I didn't said that's a bad answer, it's fine, but change the src of an image on scroll / resize event is hard to proccess. This kind of event needs to be managed carefully. My upvote to you.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude @t1m0n Fair enough, if you guys say so, i'll use the better performance way then. But still im having to move the variables including `timeout;` into the `$(window).on('scoll',function(){` to make it work. Otherwise the whole function doesnt work. Thanks a lot btw. <3

Answer (score 1):

`content` property should only works in `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements. If it's working on Chrome this way, Chrome has a bug (as usual).

Write as this:

```
 .affix .limg::before {
     content: url(../images/secondlogo.png);
 }
```

It should work in all browsers.

More info:

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content
- CSSTricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/

Comment: as i've already stated this method is not working. it stops working on chrome too.